# Recover inbound emails on Exchange?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange

Have an exchange server that for some reason wasn't delivering inbound e-mails from outside the domain.

I restarted the Transport service and some of the in-bound emails sent in the last 10 minutes or so went through; but there were some sent 20-30 minutes before that never arrived.

What happened to those?  Is there a way to find out?  The user who sent them did not receive a rejection notice.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the e-mail finally came through - even the older stuff.  it just took a bit for it to push it all out of the inbound queue apparently.  Still not sure why the transport services was doing everything except delivering the inbound mail - but at least it's up now.

Comment: Are you sure that they where ever delivered to the Transport queue? 

If another mail server tried to deliver e-mail to your Exchange server, and didn't succeed, it's not gonna keep trying indefinitely. It will retry the delivery in intervals until the delivery either succeeds, or the delivery retry operation expires

Comment: yes - the emails were sitting in the transport queue and all came through once the transport service was restarted.  I'm not sure why that happened; but the restart of the services pushed it all through.